# loading inner class without loading the enclosing class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I was bit confused when is the inner class (non static) gets loaded by the jvm  . Is it dependent on the outer class. or can it be separately loaded without loading the outer class ?

Answer (score 14):

Given that an inner class has a field with reference to an instance of the enclosing class, I don't see how it *could* be loaded without loading the enclosing class.

A static nested class may well be different, as that's genuinely independent of its enclosing class.

Comment: What if x.getEnclosingClass() is used for a static nested class?

Comment: @j4nbur53: Well as I said, it may well be different - I haven't investigated.